# Vector's first element changrs value

Tags: c++, vector

I have a do while loop which purpose is to build an array containing a list of available DLLs.

```
  do{
    DLL_List.push_back((char*)FindFileData.cFileName);
    cout << "DLL 0 IS" << DLL_List[0];
    }

while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
```

The problem : the value of DLL_List[0] changes at each iteration (with the name of the new found DLL file) ! I can see it thanks to cout. Why ? I thought push_back does not modify the previous, am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the decleration of DLL_List?

Comment: The problem is likely in a piece of code you're not showing us.  Where does `DLL_List` get created?  Does anything else modify it?  What is its type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're storing a pointer to a string that changes when you call `FindNextFile` (although you forgot to tell us exactly what `DLL_List` is, so I can't be completely sure).

Store `std::string` instead. That will keep hold of a copy of the string, not just a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks it was obvious. You saved me a lot of time.